# Firebase Firestore : Prevent Double booking in date range Android-Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, logic

Hi I am saving data for room bookings in cloud firestore, the main fields are:

```
startdate : TimeStamp
enddate : TimeStamp
```

I'm trying to find some logic to prevent double bookings, i.e no two bookings with intersecting date ranges. Any ideas for implementing this functionality will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of operation isn't possible with rules alone since you can't run a query. Instead, this would need to manage this kind of process from within [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#java_2) which you can invoke from within your app.

[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) is considered a controlled and authoritative source compared to your client app where it typically runs with the admin SDK which bypasses [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules), allowing you to do complex queries that your clients cannot do reliably. This is helpful if the client is only able to read their respective bookings and if you want to ensure that a client isn't bypassing the booking logic with hacking tools.

With this sensitive operation, you should also be using transactions to finalize the booking as you can potentially have multiple bookings at the same time conflict. With this, Firebase Cloud Functions uses Node.js to run with support for Javascript and Typescript.

[Firestore transactions for Node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at the transactions but can you please elaborate how cloud functions can handle this situation?

Comment: amended my answer to explain Cloud Functions